# class sendAPICallback extends dAPIMessage { ^ TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Now i have a new error
if you can pls help me thx

the full error

````
class sendAPICallback extends dAPIMessage {
                              ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\node_modules\←[4mdiscord-buttons←[24m\src\v12\Classes\APIMessage.js:9:31)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\node_modules\←[4mdiscord-buttons←[24m\src\v12\Classes\WebhookClient.js:2:20)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m```
the full error ^^
````

Comment: What discord.js version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[discord-buttons](https://github.com/discord-buttons/discord-buttons/blob/main/src/index.js) has a dependency of [discord.js v12](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js/v/12.5.3) which used to have a [`Structure#extend`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Structures?scrollTo=extend) method for [`ExtendableStructures`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/ExtendableStructure) which has been completed **removed** from the library itself as per [this pull request](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/6027), the developer of `discord-buttons` has refused to continue the package and is therefore in an archived state.

You have two options to fix your error

- Downgrade your discord.js version ( suggested ) 
  Run this in your console:

```sh
npm uninstall discord.js 
npm install discord.js@12.5.3
```

- Rewrite your bot's source using new Message Component methods added to discord.js v13 ( optional )