# discordjs buttons issue with Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my command:

```
//comando button test
    if(prefix&&comando === 'button'){
        const embMessage = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Teste de botões')
        .setDescription('Esse é um teste de botões')

        const yes = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle('green')
        .setLabel('Sim')
        .setID('smart')

        const no = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle('red')
        .setLabel('Não')
        .setID('dumbass')

        message.channel.send({embeds:[embMessage], buttons:[yes, no]})
    }
```

But I'm having this issue:

```
class sendAPICallback extends dAPIMessage {
                              ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

In that case, I can't run the bot code. :(

```
"discord-buttons": "^4.0.0"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class sendAPICallback extends dAPIMessage { ^ TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69063613/class-sendapicallback-extends-dapimessage-typeerror-class-extends-value-und)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros fixed the run error, but the buttons doesn't appeared. and also, all my old commands isn't working. thx but i think, i will keep up my job without buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make them be sent "buttons" should be changed into "components"

```
message.channel.send({embeds:[embMessage], components:[yes, no]});
```

And as far as i know it should be an action row

```
message.channel.send({embeds:[embMessage], components:[new discord.MessageActionRow().components([yes, no])]});
```

And there you have it

Update: Just realized your using buttons package so idk if it will change a thing or not